# Returning a pointer to the result of an operation +

Tags: c++

I have this code which works perfectly :

```
        int* a;
        int* b;
        *a = 10;
        *b = 5;
        int *c;
        int t;
        t=*a+*b;
        c = &t;
```

At the end, c points to t which is equal to 15.

Now, I want to do the exact same thing with an abstact class myObject.
I have :

```
    myObject* a;
    myObject* b;
    *a = myObject();
    *b = myObject2();
    myObject *c;
    myObject t; // Of course, this fails since myObject is an abstract class
    t=*a+*b; 
    c = &t;
```

To avoid creating a buffer variable, and to be able to get a pointer to the result of my addition, I've done this :

```
myObject* a;
myObject* b;
*a = myObject();
*b = myObject();
myObject* c;
c = &(*a+*b);
```

This code works exactly as I wanted to but I'm afraid this code is not legit. I fear that the memory pointed by `*c` could be erased at any moment. Is this the good way to do this ?

I'm sorry If this question have already been posted, I've been searching for hours without getting an answer.

EDIT 1 : It seems that I did not correctly explained my problem :
Let's say that `myObject` can be an `int`, a `double` or a `float`.
I don't know which of these I have when creating `a` and `b`, this is why I have a pointer of type `*myObject` .
I have defined every possible combination between adding an int with an int, an int with a double ...
Thanks to this, I can now add two myObject even when ignoring the real type pointed by my pointer `*myObject`.
The problem know is that I want to get a pointer to the result of my operator+ with gives back a myObject&.

I hope this is a little more clear.

Thanks

Comment: Your code which "works perfectly" has Undefined Behaviour - you just got lucky (or maybe unlucky) in that it didn't crash.

Comment: This is what I suspected, but I don't see how to fix this. Coud you point me to the right direction ?

Comment: Instead of using a dangling pointer as in `*a = myObject();` you should probably be using `a = new myObject();` (assuming `myObject` is the name of the class).

Comment: I can't do that since myObject() and myObject2() are also abstract ! In reality, a myObject pointer can point to 4 differents classes...

Comment: I think we have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here - you need to start with the underlying problem which you are actually trying to solve with your abstract classes, not an optimistic guess at a solution that can't actually work.

Comment: If they are abstract classes that you cannot instantiate, then how do you want to add two instances? Please post your _actual_ problem, not the broken attempt at one possible solution :)

Comment: I've edited my post. Hopefully I'd better show my actual problem :).

Comment: So, is myObject an abstract class or a class that makes abstraction of the used primitive type or just a type that is specified later (template)?

Comment: It's an abstract class !

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of code of the form

`int* a; *a = 10;`

etc. is *undefined*: `a` does not point to memory that you own, so you can't *dereference* it. Your code may well "work perfectly", but in reality the compiler reserves the right to eat your cat.

In C++, you tend to use `new` to construct an object if it's not feasible to use *automatic* or `static` storage. The result of `new` is a pointer of the created type. You should store that for a subsequent `delete`. Consider writing

```
A* a = new A();
/*some code*/
delete a;
```

assuming `A` has a *default* constructor, or more simply

```
A a;
```

or even the more flashy

```
A a{};
```

if *automatic* storage duration is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

***Thou shall never dereference uninitialized pointers***, it invokes undefined behaviour which is **evil**.

You must absolutely make you pointers reference true variables before using them. You can use `new` as explained by @Bathsheba (but do not forget to `delete` then), or simply use the address of an existing variable:

```
int var_a;
int *a = &var_a;
...
```

It is the same when using objects:

```
A* a;
A* b;
a = new myObject();  // don't forget to delete the new allocated pointers
b = new myObject2();
```

And then:

```
A c = (*a + *b);      // do define a true object
```

That last part is another problem: `*a + *b` creates a *temporary* object which will be destroyed at the end of the full expression (when semi colon `;` is reached). If you affect its address to a pointer, you will end with a *dangling* pointer, meaning it points to a deallocated memory that can be overwritten at any moment => again invoking Undefined Behaviour

Comment: Noting that it's UB to *read* either `*a` *or* `var_a` until `var_a` is initialised (either through itself or via the pointer).

Comment: But what If I want a pointer to an abstract class ? I can't use new.

Comment: You *can't* create an instance of an abstract class. That the whole point of them. You need to create an instance of a derived class. But you can assign that instance to a pointer of the abstract class type.

Comment: @Bathsheba Is it UB to access uninitialized variable?

Comment: To *read* its value, yes it is. But you *can* take its address.

Comment: @Bathsheba If i read its value its going to give me a garbage value(whatever happens to be in that memory location), which would not be desirable but how is it undefined behavior?

Comment: @Bathsheba OK, that was a short answer :)

Comment: @bkVnet: there may be different underlying causes for undefined behaviour. Reading an unitialized memory should not cause more harm than getting random. **But** compilers are allowed to assume that your code will never invoke undefined behaviour and optimize out any branch that could read an uninitialized memory, which now becomes really harmful!

Comment: @SergeBallesta: the Itanium chip traps on reading an uninitialised value, but your last point is a good one.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I see, that make sense. Thanks.